# mongodb compass follow object reference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

My company gave me a MongoDB database to study. I open it in Compass and discover that it is generously supplied with parent and child ID links. I try right clicking on one of those objectIDs to dereference it – expecting a menu item to go and see the referenced object in its native collection. Most obvious thing in the world, right? No such luck. Double-click? No, that gets you an opportunity to EDIT the field. Is there some decent way to do the thing that I want to do?

If not, this is a GAPING hole in the user interface design and I wonder if there is another UI that fills it.

Comment: So, after almost a year of _"study"_, what did you decide to do?

Answer (score -1):

There are some other GUI application available for mongoDb. I would recommend to try [Studio 3t](https://studio3t.com/)